# Send only audio output with HDMI

Tags: audio, hdmi, tv

I have my laptop connected to TV using HDMI cable.

But I only want to transmit audio, because I want to use my TV as speakers, nothing else. So the video is useless.

Is this possible? I've only checked if it's possible to only play audio in my TV settings but I can't find any. So there must be a solution with the PC.

I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: Assume you mean Windows 8.1?

Comment: Oh! Yes, of course. I must have missed a key.